# Regex to change Uppercase to Propercase inside strings, but only the full uppercase strings

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Example string:

```
This is an EXAMPLE SENTENCE, just do give YOU AN Example on Monday, BUT NOT FOR Friday.
```

Expected output:

```
This is an Example Sentence, just do give You An Example on Monday, But Not For Friday.
```

I've tried Propper, but this changes every first letter from every word to uppercase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the case using Regular Expressions, here's what you can try instead:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(word,JOIN(" ",IF(EXACT(UPPER(word),word),PROPER(word),word)))(SPLIT(A1," ")))
```

This formula is `SPLIT`ting the sentence by the space `" "` to separate each word and uses `IF` to check if each word converted to `UPPER`case is `EXACT`ly the same as the word not converted, if it is, it replaces it with `PROPER` casing, otherwise it keeps it as it is. Finally, it `JOIN`s the words back together.

Comment: `word_array` or `words` might be a more appropriate term.

Comment: While it's true that `word` in `LAMBDA(word,...)` refers to an array, when we do the comparison we are comparing each word individually so I prefer to use the singular noun.

Answer (score 2):

### Arrayformula

You need to specifiy your range once in a `Byrow()` range, in this case `A2:A`

```
=ArrayFormula(
 BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, IF(x="",,
 LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(" ",1,MAP(r,PROPER(r), LAMBDA(i,a, 
           IF(REGEXMATCH(i, "\b[A-Z]+\b")*1<>1,i,PROPER(a))))))
       (SPLIT(x," "))))))
```

[image]

### One Cell

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(" ",1,MAP(r,PROPER(r), LAMBDA(i,a, 
           IF(REGEXMATCH(i, "\b[A-Z]+\b")*1<>1,i,PROPER(a))))))
       (SPLIT(A2," ")))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`MAP`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) - [**`PROPER`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094133) - [**`REGEXMATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)